# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, usecallback

```
const Standings = () => {
  const [table, setTable] = useState([]);
  const [id, setId] = useState("2021");

  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch(`http://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/${id}/standings`, {
      headers: { "X-Auth-Token": process.env.REACT_APP_FOOTBALL_KEY },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setTable(data.standings[0].table);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

I'm also using fetchData outside of render, so cannot put that inside useEffect

Also tried this but its fetching data infinitely.I've been unable to find a solution that stops the infinite loop.

```
  const [table, setTable] = useState([]);
  const [id, setId] = useState("2021");

  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  const fetchData = useCallback(() => {
    fetch(`http://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/${id}/standings`, {
      headers: { "X-Auth-Token": process.env.REACT_APP_FOOTBALL_KEY },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setTable(data.standings[0].table);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchData]);
```

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15865

Answer (score 3):

You've incorrectly omitted the dependency array so `fetchData` is a new reference each render cycle. The `useCallback` hook needs at least an empty dependency array in order to provide a stable callback reference.

[useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

> ```
> const memoizedCallback = useCallback(
>   () => {
>     doSomething(a, b);
>   },
>   [a, b],
> );
> ```
>
> **Note**
>
> The array of dependencies is not passed as arguments to the callback.
> Conceptually, though, that’s what they represent: ***every value
> referenced inside the callback should also appear in the dependencies
> array***.

The `id` is a dependency for the `fetchData` function if you are trying to memoize it in the `useCallback` hook.

```
const [id, setId] = useState("2021");

const fetchData = useCallback(() => {
  fetch(`http://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/${id}/standings`, {
    headers: { "X-Auth-Token": process.env.REACT_APP_FOOTBALL_KEY },
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      setTable(data.standings[0].table);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}, [id]);

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, [fetchData]);
```